# Have you managed to get results when running the query SELECT * FROM information_schema.views in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is there a bug in the `information_schema.views` implementation in **AWS Athena**?

I'm getting 0 rows returned when running the query `SELECT * FROM information_schema.views` in AWS Athena even though the database I'm running on has tables and views in it.

Wanted to check if anyone else is facing the same issue.

I'm trying to fetch the view definition script for ALL views in the **AWS Athena** database as a single result set instead of using the `SHOW CREATE VIEW statement`.

Comment: I raised a case with AWS Support and they were able to replicate the issue. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS system catalog table doesn't return any results. Waiting for a response from AWS Support now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 
`SHOW TABLES IN example_database;` to get information about tables in `Athena` database.

And the loop through use `describe` `query` to fetch details.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hi Red Boy - I'm looking for the view definition - the equivalent of the SHOW CREATE VIEW output.

Comment: 'Views' are logical tables rather then physical, hence above query will return both 'views' and 'tables'